# C# LDAP user change password failed. Is SSL connection must?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API (platform independent) to change the LDAP user password. I'm using the library `Novell.Directory.Ldap`.

This is my code:

```
var ldapHost = "192/168.*.*";
var loginDN = "CN=something,DC=something";   //loginDn of the user itself or admin 
var opassword = "Abcd@11111111";  //oldpassword
var npassword = "Xyzw@22222222";  //newpassword
npassword =  '"' + npassword + '"';

LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();

Console.WriteLine("Connecting to:" + ldapHost);

conn.Connect(ldapHost, LdapConnection.DefaultPort);
conn.Bind(loginDN, opassword);

LdapModification[] modifications = new LdapModification[2];
LdapAttribute deletePassword = new LdapAttribute("userPassword", opassword);
modifications[0] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Delete, deletePassword);

LdapAttribute addPassword = new LdapAttribute("userPassword", npassword);
modifications[1] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Add, addPassword);

conn.Modify(loginDN, modifications);
```

I am testing this code for a Windows AD domain as well as Linux OpenLDAP. Both LDAP server's users have the attribute property `userPassword` present.

When I run this code `LdapModification.ADD` throws an error that `No such attribute userPassword.` when I try to find the solution I get people using attribute `unicodePwd`, but it needs an SSL connection.

Is the SSL connection a **must** for AD domains and Open LDAP? Or how else to solve the above error? Please help.

Comment: yes, with AD you need SSL for changing password using LDAP is a must, there are other ways all documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/password-change-mechanisms . I didn't work with OPENLdap yet... I hope this help

Comment: But when I was using ```System.DirectoryServices``` ```ChangePassword``` method, it was possible without SSL connection.

Comment: System.DirectoryServices likely is using one of the other ways/protocols to do the password change, there are 6 and none of them requires SSL except LDAP as stated on that page from docs microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While AD has a `userPassword` attribute, it's just a pointer to the `unicodePwd` attribute, which is the real password attribute. But `userPassword` doesn't always work, as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8). For Active Directory, you're better off using `unicodePwd` directly.

[The documentation for `unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) says that you require either SSL or SASL encryption to set the attribute. SASL would usually be done with Kerberos. If you were using `DirectoryEntry`, that's easily done by specifying [`AuthenticationTypes.Sealing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#fields). With `Novell.Directory.Ldap`, I don't know if that's possible, and [this open issue](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/28) suggests that it isn't (yet).

Unless you're willing to switch to using `Sytem.DirectoryServices` (which, in .NET Core, would lock you into running your app on Windows only), then I think you are stuck requiring SSL.

The `unicodePwd` attribute also requires a very specific format. The documentation says:

> the DC requires that the password value be specified in a UTF-16 encoded Unicode string containing the password surrounded by quotation marks, which has been BER-encoded as an octet string per the Object(Replica-Link) syntax.

In C#, that's easily done like this:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\"NewPassword\"")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So my next should be enabling SSL on the AD domain and OpenLDAP.

Comment: Hey, I can update the windows AD domain user password successfully. But for  OpenLDAP, it is giving an error on ```conn.Modify```  i.e  ```no such attribute unicodePwd``` .  Does the  OpenLDAP use some different attribute for userPassword?

Comment: @Versh OpenLDAP probably uses `userPassword`. You will have to treat AD and OpenLDAP differently.